# Iterating DataGridView gets only the values of the first two columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that has got 5 columns. I am using a `For Next` loop to iterate each column's value, but for some reason it only works for column 1 and 2.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As Decimal
    Dim b As Decimal
    Dim i As Integer
    a = 5.23

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        b = a * (DataGridView1.Item(i, 0).Value)
        MessageBox.Show(b)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate each column of the first row then you need to loop up to `DataGridView.Columns.Count - 1` instead.

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
```

Comment: yes it worked but, also this code calculate second row, I want to calculate first row values  only

Comment: thats the code what ı wrote above, with this code i saw only first 2 coulumn value in messagebox,  no coloumn 2,3 and 4 5

Comment: @Emrah : It's not the same, no. I changed the loop from `For i = 0 To DataGridView1.**Rows**.Count - 1` to `For i = 0 To DataGridView1.**Columns**.Count - 1`

Comment: @Emrah : I edited out the other code as well. It should be clear now :). It's only the first line of the loop that needs to be changed.

Comment: it is very clear now, thank you very much your support. I acceppt your solution and voted acordingly. :)

Comment: @Emrah : Glad I could help! And sorry for the confusion... Good luck with your project! :)